# I am confused with the outcome below

Tags: solidity, concurrency

Two contracts (code are for illustrative purposes only. Assume all syntax are correct):

```
contract CA
{
    function FA() public
    {
        // Invoke CB.FB() multiple times
    }
}
```

And

```
contract CB
{
    function FB() public
    {
        // require(now < 12:00pm);
    }

    function FC() public
    {
       // require(now >= 12:00pm);
    }
}
```

Everything executing smoothly until the following scenario:

11:55am    Invoked FA()

12:10pm    Invoked FC()

12:20pm    FA() invoked FB() multiple times, starting to receive events from FB(). Expecting some of it to fail, since some were processed beyond 12:00pm. But magically all passed

12:20pm    FC() were taken place but failed unexpectedly

Please take note that, I were running all these within a private chain. So it is processed quite fast.

Comment: Without knowing more, the simplest answer would be that your nodes' clocks aren't synchronized as you would expect. If you were hours behind (maybe you're expecting localtime not UTC?) the consistent result would be exactly what you've outlined. Take a look at your transaction records and inspect the block time and post back with those details.

Comment: Block time is not very accurate, @Motoma's explanation is the most likely. Check your block timestamps. You can even have block N with a earlier timestamp than block N-1.